# Build Pipeline using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure-pipelines

I am currently working in azure DevOps and PowerShell. I need to build an azure pipeline through API using PowerShell. I have done something to list my projects in my organization. Kindly help me to build a pipeline through API similarly using PowerShell.

```
         function GetUrl() {
param(
    [string]$orgUrl, 
    [hashtable]$header, 
    [string]$AreaId
)

# Build the URL for calling the org-level Resource Areas REST API for the RM APIs
$orgResourceAreasUrl = [string]::Format("{0}/_apis/resourceAreas/{1}?api-preview=5.0-preview.1", 
$orgUrl, $AreaId)

# Do a GET on this URL (this returns an object with a "locationUrl" field)
$results = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $orgResourceAreasUrl -Headers $header

# The "locationUrl" field reflects the correct base URL for RM REST API calls
if ("null" -eq $results) {
    $areaUrl = $orgUrl
}
else {
    $areaUrl = $results.locationUrl
}

return $areaUrl
}


 $orgUrl = "https://dev.azure.com/<my organization>/"

 $personalToken = "<my path>"
 Write-Host "Initialize authentication context" -ForegroundColor Yellow
 $token = 
  [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
   $header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}

   $coreAreaId = "79134c72-4a58-4b42-976c-04e7115f32bf"
   $tfsBaseUrl = GetUrl -orgUrl $orgUrl -header $header -AreaId $coreAreaId

   $projectsUrl = "$($tfsBaseUrl)_apis/projects?api-version=5.0"

   $projects = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $projectsUrl -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" - 
   Headers $header

   $projects.value | ForEach-Object {
   Write-Host $_.name
   }
```

I have my output listing my projects while running this code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you mean "queue a build" for an existing pipeline by "build a pipeline",

you can call below [queue build api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) to queue your pipeline to run.

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1`

Below is a simple powershell example to queue a build.

```
$body = '
{ 
        "definition": {
            "id": number
        } 
}
'
$token =   [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($personalToken)"))
$header = @{authorization = "Basic $token"}


$Uri = "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/builds?api-version=5.1"
$buildresponse = Invoke-RestMethod -Method Post -ContentType "application/json" -Uri $Uri -Body $body -Headers $header
write-host $buildresponse
```

> If you mean "create a new pipeline" by "build a pipeline". You can check [build definition create Api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/definitions/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).

[Here](http://chen.about-powershell.com/2018/07/create-vsts-build-definitions-using-powershell/) is an example to create build definition via powershell scripts.

However it is suggested to create them from azure devops portal, as this [thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/62947/creating-a-build-definition-via-api) pointed out the reason.

You can check this [quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/create-first-pipeline?view=azure-devops&tabs=tfs-2018-2) to get started with YAML pipelines and then [customize your pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/customize-pipeline?view=azure-devops) . There are some conceptual topics that you may need to customize your pipeline such as [variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch) and [tasks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/tasks?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/get-started/key-pipelines-concepts?view=azure-devops) for more concepts. You can also follow this [learning tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/create-a-build-pipeline/?view=azure-devops) provided by Microsoft.

Comment: This helps to queue my pipelines through API. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you meant by pipeline here. You can use any of the APIs available in [MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/core/projects/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) site.

For projects you can use :

```
function get_projects {
    do
    {
        $uri="https://dev.azure.com/$Org/_apis/projects?continuationToken=$ContinuationToken&api-version=5.1"
        $ProjSets=Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $Uri -Method Get -ContentType "application/json" -Headers $header
        $continuationToken = $ProjSets.Headers.'x-ms-continuationtoken'
        $ProjectSet=$projset.content | ConvertFrom-Json
        $projects+=$ProjectSet.value
        }while ($continuationToken)
        write-host "$continuationToken" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $projects.name
        $projects.count

}

get_projects
```

To get all projects in the organization that the authenticated user has access to, you can use the below:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?api-version=5.1
```

OR this with additional prameters:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/projects?stateFilter={stateFilter}&$top={$top}&$skip={$skip}&continuationToken={continuationToken}&getDefaultTeamImageUrl={getDefaultTeamImageUrl}&api-version=5.1
```

You can use `Invoke-RestMethod` or `Invoke-WebRequest` to hit those URLs and get the results as well.

Hope it helps.