# Azure pipeline to run two or more independent pipelines from a wrapper pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

Is it possible to create a wrapper pipeline in Azure DevOps that simply runs two or more independent pipelines (in parallel) and does nothing else?

I have a problem to solve. and the scenario looks like this "*

1. In my project, I have say 9 teams and each designing separate Sanity Test Script. All of them have their own existing Sanity Pipeline. i.e. 9 Sanity Pipelines*
2. There is a plan that there will be only One Master/ Wrapper pipeline and this in turn calls upon 9 child pipelines pertaining to Sanity
3. When master run by Release Engineer or IT Area lead to get report, the child pipelines run in Parallel
4. Also in master Pipeline, I do not want to be too much lengthy. Simply I want to mention the name of Child pipeline in my individual Job tag ( with params may be ) and it will run. easy configurable " So I was thinking to use following at my master pipeline: resources: pipelines:
   pipeline: Sanity1 Source: P00xxx-Sanity1-Pipeline
   pipeline: Sanity2 Source: P00xxx-Sanity2-Pipeline
   This list should be easily expandable.......
   Then How in Jobs--> Job --> Steps can I run the pipeline using alias, e.g. Sanity1 ?? Any example code snippet?

Comment: I don't have a ready answer but you can split the steps from the rest of the build process by using templates. That was both the individual builds can include their 1 steps template in a job and the big build can include 9 jobs each referencing a different steps template, one from each sanity build.

Comment: This repo shows how to split the steps from the job definition, making is easy to re-use the steps in multiple pipelines: https://www.github.com/Microsoft/vsts-team-calendar/tree/master/

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to take the pipeline and leverage templates.  The wrapper pipeline can call a template which will leverage all the desired tasks and execution and can be setup to run in parallel as part of the pipeline.

Here's a blog post about [this](https://blog.johnfolberth.com/multi-stage-yaml-pipelines-in-a-micros-service-architecture/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerShell and rest API ([Builds - Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/queue?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1)). Add [PowerShell step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops) and compose any run sequence. Here you can find different examples to queue builds:

1. [Build Pipeline using powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59836151/build-pipeline-using-powershell/59851851)
2. [Trigger another build exist in project in Azure Devops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64824802/trigger-another-build-exist-in-project-in-azure-devops/64852348)

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, you can try to use parameters and conditions to set up the pipeline.

You can try the following Yaml sample:

```
trigger:
- none
parameters:
- name: pipeline1
  displayName: Gradle sample #PipelineName
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: pipeline2
  displayName: groovy-spring-boot-restdocs-example.git #PipelineName
  type: boolean
  default: false
- name: pipeline3
  displayName: Gradle sample-CI  #PipelineName
  type: boolean
  default: false



pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

steps:
- ${{ if eq(parameters.pipeline1, true) }}:
  - task: TriggerPipeline@1
    inputs:
     serviceConnection: 'TestBuild'
     project: '966ef694-1a7d-4c35-91f3-41b8c5363c48'
     Pipeline: 'Build'
     buildDefinition: 'Gradle sample' #PipelineName
     Branch: 'master'

- ${{ if eq(parameters.pipeline2, 'true') }}:
  - task: TriggerPipeline@1
    inputs:
     serviceConnection: 'TestBuild'
     project: '966ef694-1a7d-4c35-91f3-41b8c5363c48'
     Pipeline: 'Build'
     buildDefinition: 'groovy-spring-boot-restdocs-example.git' #PipelineName
     Branch: 'master'

...
```

**Explanation:**

I use the `Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline` task from the [Trigger Azure DevOps Pipeline Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=maikvandergaag.maikvandergaag-trigger-pipeline) to trigger the child pipelines.

The parameters is used to list the pipeline names and the if condition is used to determine whether the pipeline name is selected.

**Result:**

When you run the pipeline you could select the checkbox.

[image]

If the pipeline name has been selected, the corresponding task will run and trigger the corresponding pipeline.

This should make the selection interface clearer.

Comment: Let me check with my Azure Admin to install this plugin. I will come back..

Comment: Hi @user2571588. Feel free to let me know your progress. if you have  any questions, I will still be here to help you.

Comment: Hi @user2571588. To follow up, do you have any update about this ticket?